# PayPal SDK Insert an information in the paypal transaction

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am developing a page that sends me a payment to activate a paid plan of a discord bot. So I used paypall sdk.

This is my js code:

```
 paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            color: 'blue',
            shape: 'pill'
        },
        createOrder:function (data, actions){
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount:{
                        value: '1.00'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
         onApprove:function (data, actions){
                return actions.order.capture().then(function (details){
                    console.log(details)
                
                })
            }
    }).render('#paypal-payment-button');
```

What do I need to add to enter information in the transaction?

---

**What do I mean by information in the transaction?** I mean a string that identifies the server that must obtain the upgrade (so I need it to verify the transaction and then activate the paid plan at that particular guild id, so, the server id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an [Orders create request body](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body)'s purchase_units , you can include an arbitrary `custom_id`.